# python mysqldb printing text even if no print statement in the code

Tags: python, mysql

This is my program

> import MySQLdb as mdb
>
> from MySQLdb import IntegrityError
>
> conn = mdb.connect("localhost", "asdf", "asdf", "asdf")

when the connect function is called python prints some text ("h" in the shell).
This happens only if I execute the script file from a particular folder.
If I copy the same script file to some other folder "h" is not printed.

actually i had this line previously in the same script for testing

> print "h"

but now i have removed the line from the script. But still it is printed. What happen to my folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting *.pyc files. Secondly use script with -v option so that you can view from where the file is being imported